# Can`t get python , pyautogui and kivy working together

Tags: python, kivy, window, pyautogui

So started learning python a few weeks ago , so probably a noobs question but...
When  I run this code on Windows 10:

```
# code 1
import pyautogui


janela = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('Google Chrome')
janela[0].activate()
```

It focuses the desired window....and I can maximize, close, minimize , etc..with pyautogui

but if I try to assign to a kivy button, I get an error.

```
# code 2 py file

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import pyautogui


class atest(App):
   def build(self):
       a = bs()
       return a


class bs(BoxLayout):
   def roda(self):
       janela = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('Google Chrome')
       janela[0].activate()


ja = atest()
ja.run()
```

```
#code 2 kv file

<bs>:
    Button:
        on_press: root.roda()
```

it render the button but when clicked:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_RECT instance instead of pointer to RECT
```

At first I thought it was a problem with `pyautogui`, so I tested with code 1 and it worked, then I thought it was a problem with my application so I tested with code 2, and since I get the problem with a simple button, maybe I'm not calling it the correct way..

followed the recommendations here: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/353
but I think it's a different problem.

`edit: All methods in pyautogui work except the ones related to pygetwindow (getAllWindows(),getWindowsWithTitle('Untitled'), getActiveWindow(),getActiveWindow().title)`

`edit2: if I change the function called by the button so it runs code1 it works as expected..`

```
def roda(self):
        os.system(r"C:\Users\tetsuo\anaconda3\envs\k37\python.exe " "code1.py ")
```

Comment: Are you running your scripts in the same way? What you're doing seems fine, so it's worth confirming they're running the same version of pyautogui, in the same way.

Comment: yes running both the same way, and in the same terminal, I also tried diferent version of pyautogui as suggested on the github post.

Answer (score 0):

So, gave up on focusing a window with pyautogui and used pywinauto:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
def roda(self): 
    app = Application()
    app.connect(title_re=".*Chrome")
    app_dialog = app.top_window()
    app_dialog.set_focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem and believe I found a solution.

Looks like pywinauto had a similar issue as I found a link to the solution from their github issues page.

On this page: https://bugs.python.org/issue22552

> The ctypes global LibraryLoader instances are convenient for Windows scripts and applications. Actually what they cache is the library (a CDLL instance), which in turn caches function pointers.
>
> Python packages, on the other hand, shouldn't use these particular loaders. As you've experienced, doing so can lead to conflicting definitions for restype, argtypes, and errcheck. Instead create a private loader such as cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL), or windll = LibraryLoader(WinDLL).
>
> Doing this would be pretty much pointless on non-Windows platforms. To gain the benefit of the cache you'd have to use subscripting such as cdll['libc.so.6']. It's simpler to use libc = CDLL('libc.so.6').

And so editing pyautogui source file _pygetwindow_win.py to include at the top

`windll = ctypes.LibraryLoader(ctypes.WinDLL)`

And then change all calls of ctypes.windll... to instead reference the windll variable you just created. I guess this is more of a bug in pygetwindow than pyautogui